# How to add ttf file in less using typography.less file?

Tags: magento2, css, less

I want to call .ttf file instead of .woff2 file in typography.less. But, it's not call and return 404 error.

Code :

```
.lib-font-face(
        @family-name: @roboregular,
        @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/robo-regular-webfont',
        @font-weight: normal,
        @font-style: normal,
        @font-display: swap
    );
```

How to call it?

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you simply create .woff & .woff2 extension using the online tools.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'roboregular';
    src:  url('../fonts/Akkurat-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

You can change the font path according to your directory.